# Server side language for native android application

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing a native Android app. My requirement needs a database like MySQL or Oracle and I'm thinking of using a REST web service to connect to database. I'm more familiar with php. My question is, Should i use only java to develop web service for a native android application ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Hybrid refers to the code running on the device, not to the services it's calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

Hybrid is a web app, primarily built using HTML5 and JavaScript, that is then wrapped inside a thin native container that provides access to native platform features

While using of web services does not make your app hybrid.

Comment: Do i have to use only java to develop a web service for native android app?

Comment: You can use any language you want to use to develop a web service, not necessary JAVA